# Можно ли в условии с указателями опустить nullptr

Tags: c++, указатели, c++11, условия

Есть условие:

```
if ((p != nullptr) && (p->left == nullptr) && (p->right == nullptr)){....
```

Можно ли его записать как:

```
if ((p) && (!p->left) && (!p->right){....
```

Или смысл условия все же поменяется?

P.S. `p` - это указатель на класс (`Node*`)

Comment: можно. условиия эквивалентны

Comment: Смысл условия не поменяется, но удобочитаемость снизится. Как следствие, поддерживать такой код будет сложнее.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Оператор `if` требует, выражение типа `bool`. Если выражение имеет другой тип, то он будет преобразовано в `bool`.

Алгоритм преобразования указателя в `bool` прост. Нулевой указатель преобразуется в `false`, любой ненулевой указатель  в `true`.

Comment: `Если выражение имеет другой тип, то он будет преобразовано в bool.` не все может так просто быть преобразованным в bool.